# Create Workflow 2010 custom activity on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-activity

I'm using a Sharepoint 2010 Workflow to change list item permissions. 
Everything's working fine but now I'm required to assign permissions to a list of users which will be contained on a user field with multiple users separated by semicolons. So from what I know I will need to write a custom workflow action to achieve this.

So my question is, is it possible to deploy workflow 2010 activities in SharePoint 2013? What special considerations should I make to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as it stay a SharePoint 2010 workflow in SharePoint 2013. Just deploy it just as you would and you should be able to use it.